# How to do inferential statistical testing on multiple rows out of only mean and standard deviation data in R?

Tags: r, bigdata, data-science, inference

So I already asked that question on Cross Validated, but was redirected here:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/475706/290532?sem=2

Originally, I started out with two .csv files, each 7 GB in size. Once read in into R they each hold about 20 GB of RAM. That is why I calculated the files df1 and df2, which only contain a mean and the standard deviation. Both files have about 8 million rows. The sample size "behind" every mean/standard deviation-pair is 157.

`df1`:

```
ID       Mean         Standard deviation
16091071 0.1551044586 0.0120334914
16091086 0.1528095541 0.0125274201
16091147 0.3395656051 0.0186907447
16091154 0.2788547771 0.017261902
16091227 0.250456051 0.0176726877
16091236 0.2776751592 0.0175430484
```

`df2`:

```
ID       Mean         Standard deviation
16091071 0.0999431847 0.0106193089
16091086 0.3864509554 0.0181384583
16091147 0.3864509554 0.0181384583
16091154 0.0999431847 0.0106193089
16091227 0.0999431847 0.0106193089
16091236 0.0999431847 0.0106193089
```

The question now is how to do inferential statistics in R only based on mean and standard deviation data row by row while simultaneously still considering the multiple testing problem.

The discussion about the statistical feasibility was already done at Cross Validated. Here I want to ask if there is a performant solution to the effort of calculating the differences between the two sample means. So both, df1 and df2 have ID-columns. I would like to know if the mean in df1 for one ID is significantly different from the mean of the same ID in df2. And I would like to have that information for all the IDs.
If I had just one ID I would perform a Wilcoxon-test. Is there a more performant way than just looping over all IDs, performing individual Wilcoxon-tests?

Comment: Hi PolII (like polymerase 2?), I fear you cannot do a Wilcox test without the underlying data. Remember, that test is about the *order* of the data. Perhaps rather than making this a question about how to perform a test without the required data, you should consider reframing it into a question about how to perform data analysis on very large files without reading the whole data into memory. I'd suggest checking out the [`vroom`](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2019/05/vroom-1-0-0/) package. Also be careful to ask a *specific* question, as it would be easy to ask one that is overly broad.

Comment: Hi (yes, exactly. RNA-Polymerase 2 to be precise ;) ) Thank you for your comment and your suggestion of `vroom`!